# Error: Empty response. There are no subscribers listening to that message ("x")

Tags: typescript, microservices, nestjs, messaging, messagebroker

I am trying to create microservices via Nestjs and Nats but I am getting an error  `Error: Empty response. There are no subscribers listening to that message ("checkUserExists")`
For Now I have only Gateway and Auth microservice
All necessary code and files are described below

> Gateway code

```js
import { join } from 'path';
import basicAuth from 'express-basic-auth';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { MicroserviceOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { Logger, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { ApiModulesList } from './api/api.modules.list';
import { GlobalExceptionFilter } from './exceptions';
import { swaggerConfig } from './swagger';

const logger = new Logger('Gateway Service');

const bootstrap = async () => {
    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);

    const configService = new ConfigService();
    const port = parseInt(configService.get('API_PORT', '3000'), 10);
    const apiRoutePrefix = configService.get('API_ROUTE_PREFIX', 'api');
    const apiDoc = configService.get('SWAGGER_DOC_URL', 'api-docs');
    const isSwaggerOn = configService.get('IS_SWAGGER_UI_ACTIVE', 'false').toLowerCase() === 'true';

    app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ exceptionFactory: (errors) => errors, transform: true, whitelist: true }));
    app.useGlobalFilters(new GlobalExceptionFilter());
    app.enable('trust proxy');

    app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));

    if (isSwaggerOn) {
        if (configService.get('NODE_ENV', '') !== 'development') {
            app.use(
                [`/${apiDoc}`, `/${apiDoc}-json`],
                basicAuth({
                    challenge: true,
                    users: {
                        [configService.get('BASIC_AUTH_USER_NAME', 'admin')]: configService.get(
                            'BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD',
                            'Messapps@1'
                        ),
                    },
                })
            );
        }
        const apiGuideLink = configService.get('API_GUIDE_LINK', '');
        const appName = configService.get('APPNAME', 'Project name');
        const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, swaggerConfig({ appName, port, apiGuideLink }), {
            include: ApiModulesList,
        });
        SwaggerModule.setup(apiDoc, app, document);
    }
    const natsToken = configService.get('NATS_TOKEN');
    const natsHost = configService.get('NATS_HOST', 'localhost');
    const natsPort = configService.get('NATS_PORT', '4222');

    const natsMicroservice = app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
        transport: Transport.NATS,
        options: {
            servers: [`nats://${natsHost}:${natsPort}`],
            token: natsToken,
        },
    });

    await app.startAllMicroservices();

    await app.listen(port);

    logger.debug(`API Server started at http://localhost:${port}/${apiRoutePrefix}`);
    isSwaggerOn
        ? logger.debug(`Swagger Docs runs at http://localhost${port ? ':' + port : ''}/${apiDoc} `)
        : logger.debug('Swagger Docs is OFF');
};

bootstrap().catch((error) => {
    logger.error(error);
});
```

> Gateway Service

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CheckUserExistsRequest, CheckUserExistsResponse, AuthSuccessResponse, AuthSignUpRequest } from './dto';
import { AuthType } from './auth.enums';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(@Inject('GATEWAY_AUTH_PUBLISHER') private natsClient: ClientProxy) {}

    checkUserExists(dto: CheckUserExistsRequest): Observable<CheckUserExistsResponse> {
        return this.natsClient.send<CheckUserExistsResponse, CheckUserExistsRequest>('checkUserExists', dto);
    }

}
```

> Microservice Listener

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientProxy, MessagePattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { CheckUserExistsRequest, CheckUserExistsResponse } from './dto';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    constructor(@Inject('AUTH_SERVICE') private natsClient: ClientProxy) {}

    @MessagePattern('checkUserExists')
    async checkUserExistsRes(dto: CheckUserExistsRequest): Promise<CheckUserExistsResponse> {
        console.log('checkUserExistsRes', dto);
        return { exists: true };
    }
}
```

I have tried everything but didnt get any success if anyone knows how to resolve this issue will be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the MessagePattern decorator being used directly in your service instead of the module's controller. The decorator will be ignored if it is not located within the controller

The nest documentation state:

> To create a message handler based on the request-response paradigm use
> the @MessagePattern() decorator, which is imported from the
> @nestjs/microservices package. This decorator should be used only
> within the controller classes since they are the entry points for your
> application. Using them inside providers won't have any effect as they
> are simply ignored by Nest runtime.

To solve your issue, create a controller that handles the request and passes it to the service to handle the business logic.

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessagePattern, Payload } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Controller('app')
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @MessagePattern('checkUserExists')
  async handleLoginRequest(dto: CheckUserExistsRequest): Promise<CheckUserExistsResponse> {
    return await this.appService.handleLoginRequest(dto);
  }
}
```